# Using canvas drawImage in chrome extension content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use `drawImage` on Canvas Context in injected content script from my Chrome Extension.

```
  testCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  testContext = testCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var image = new Image();
  testContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

In Chrome 26 it works ok, but in dev channel (Chrome 28) this seams broken as I got this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error
```

When I move same script directly into background page, it works without any problem.

I think this can be related to some security related change but I failed to find any relevant information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug, you should report it. Some more testing reveals that in Chrome 28.0.1498.0, the `Image` constructor does not create a valid `HTMLImageElement` instance (as seen in the screenshot below).
This code is run in the context of a Content script. The same code works fine on regular pages and in the extension's process (background page).

To work around the problem, use `document.createElement('img')` instead of `new Image()`.

[image: .appendChild(new Image()) Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8]

And don't forget to report the bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list.

Comment: Thanks! Bug reported at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238071

Comment: @Kepi I've reported a new bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245296. It turns out that the bug is not specific to `new Image()`, but also `Audio` and `Option`.