# context.drawImage() doesn't work with new Image() instance (chrome)

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, canvas, preloading

I am trying to figure out why the classic way of image preloading before drawing in canvas is firing a "Type error" on chrome.

Let's see the situation:

I try to preload images in 3 different ways:

1. creating a new Image() instance
2. creating an image element
3. creating a jQuery image object

Or if you prefer some code:

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas-1'),
    context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d'),
    image1 = new Image(),
    canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas-2'),
    context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d'),
    image2 = document.createElement('img'),
    $canvas3 = $('#canvas-3'),
    context3 = $canvas3.get(0).getContext('2d'),
    $image3 = $('<img>'),
    loadImage = function (image, context, debugIndice) {
        debugIndice = debugIndice || -1;
        image.onload = function () {
            try {
                context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log('error for debugIndice', debugIndice, e, this);
            }
        }
        image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png";
    };

loadImage(image1, context1, 1);
loadImage(image2, context2, 2);
loadImage($image3.get(0), context3, 3);
```

Please watch the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jPZ3/2/) here.

I only have a Type error for the first loadImage call.

I am using Google Chrome 27.0.1453.94 on Windows at my company, and Google Chrome 27.0.1453.93 on Mac OS X, both x64 platforms.

This code works fine in Firefox, **and even IE9** (I'm not kidding, I swear it)

Does someone knows about this Image() class problem in Chrome ?

EDIT: Here is a screen of the bug:
[image: Chrome - Image bug]

You can watch it on real size [here](http://d.pr/i/Fj0L).

This is not a big problem, anyway I will use the jQuery way, but I am really curious to see what is the cause, and why did I lose some time trying to fix it!

I took a look at this [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377375/using-canvas-drawimage-in-chrome-extension-content-script/16378270).

I am still asking as I am not sure that it is the same ?!

Comment: no "Type error" here either (Chrome 27)

Comment: Hummmm strange, can you guys say me on which platform are you working on ?

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue on Chromium 25 and Chrome 29 (dev) on Ubuntu 12.04. Are you sure it's not some kind of caching issue?

Comment: yeah, definitely sure !

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Chrome 27.0.1453.94 under Win 7 (x64). Perhaps a utility or security program is interfering with Chrome?

Comment: Happens for me as well: 27.0.1453.93 on mac, actually - it happens on stable, beta and dev. What extensions are you running?

Comment: It's not extensions, turned em all off. Still happening.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to come from any extension, it works now... I'll try to  figure out which one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not exactly a solution as this is a Chrome bug. But here is the related Chrome bug on their tracker. It is a known issue and should be fix in the - hopefully - near future: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238071

In the meantime, use `document.createElement("img")` instead of `new Image()`.

Comment: Yeah I saw this before to ask, watch the "bug" link in my question :)
Finally I'm using $('<img>') from jQuery !

Comment: I have an issue that the image isn't loaded, but the onload event did triggers anyway, so no image is drawn and an error occures.

Comment: Strang think actually, could your image itself be binary-damaged in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It pains me that this worked and I don't have a better answer, but after turning on and off all extensions, trying beta and dev channels, what finally worked was rebooting my computer. Now drawImage works just fine. :(